# The rank of a tensor is not invariant under isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V,W$ be two $K$-vector spaces; for $a\in V\otimes W$ define 
\begin{equation*}
rk(a)=\min \left\{r|a=\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha_iv_i\otimes w_i\text{ for some }\alpha_i\in K,v_i\in V,w_i\in W\right\}.
\end{equation*}

Now let $U$ be a vector space of dimension greater than 1 and consider the canonical isomorphism $i\colon (U\otimes U)\otimes U\rightarrow U\otimes (U\otimes U)$.

It should be true that the rank is not invariant under $i$, but I can't see it. :(

(BTW: this is problem 1.2.2 in Radford's "Hopf algebras")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b \in U$ be linearly independent. Then $(a \otimes b + b \otimes a) \otimes a$ has rank $1$ in $(U \otimes U) \otimes U$ whereas $a \otimes (b \otimes a) + b \otimes (a \otimes a)$ has rank $2$.

Comment: OMG! I have been playing for some time with such elements, without realizing that $a\otimes b+b\otimes a$ is just a vector in $U\otimes U$... Many thanks